# single word: person who loves the night or staying up at night

Tags: single-word-requests

What a person would be called who loves the night or staying up at night?

In both senses, like the young generation with their smartphones, and someone who just loves staying up late at night.

Answer (score 11):

A "[Night Owl](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/night-owl)" is a term for a person who prefers being awake during the late hours of the night.

> someone who enjoys staying awake all night

If you want to go with something that's more clinical sounding, you could go with "[nyctophilia](http://www.medilexicon.com/medicaldictionary.php?t=61930)"

> Preference for the night or darkness.

Comment: Less commonly "night person" or "nighthawk" (I've never personally heard the latter, but the Internet has). Night Owl is definitely the term most often used.

Comment: I prefer to label myself a *night owl*, but less charitable people are inclined to call me a [*troglodyte*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troglodyte) (one who dwells in [dark] caves). They're always telling me the early bird catches the worm, but the way I see it, the early worm ends up *being* breakfast, not *having* it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers They have some studies out recently that say smart people stay up later ;)